# Laravel new password not persisting to database when using `logoutOtherDevices`

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm trying to create a password update form in Laravel 7 i.e. a form that currently logged in users can use to change their password.

I am using the default laravel authentication package, just building upon it.

My update fuction does not seem to persist the new user password to the database. I have confirmed that my new/old password is different. After submitting the form I can still login with my old password, and the new password doesn't work. There are no errors (and I have development mode on). The database is getting a new timestamp and the hash is changing.

```
/**
 * Update current user's password
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function updatePassword(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->only(['current_password', 'password', 'password_confirmation']), [
        'current_password' => ['required'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10', 'confirmed']
    ]);
    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($request, $user) {
        if (!Hash::check($request->current_password, $user->password)) {
            $validator->errors()->add('current_password', 'The current value does not match our records.');
        }
    })->validate();
    //echo 'current password: '. $request->current_password . '<br>';
    //echo 'new password: ' . $request->password . '<br>';
    $currentPassword = $request->current_password;
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
    $user->save();
    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword);
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'msg' => 'Password updated!']);
}
```

Comment: Can u debug ($request->password) after line $currnetPassword = $request->current_password; the resultt is null ?

Comment: the result is as expected. the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out `logoutOutOtherDevices` and the new password persists to the database. Laravel provides little information on how to use the function aside from requiring the current password. Since the order of operations was update then logout of other devices, then the new password needed to be added instead of the previous.

```
Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password); // i.e. the current (new) password
```

This is due to this line of code in `logoutOtherDevices()`:

```
    $result = tap($this->user()->forceFill([
        $attribute => Hash::make($password),
    ]))->save();
```